# CloudWatch agent can not keep up with logging

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 machine running a java application with the following logback configuration:

```xml
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>/var/log/my-application/application.log</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>/var/log/my-application/application-%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    <minIndex>1</minIndex>
    <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <maxFileSize>800MB</maxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%level --- [%thread] %logger{36} : %msg%n
    </pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

If you are not familiar with logback, this configuration boils down to my application appending logging statements to the `/var/log/my-application/application.log` file until it reaches 800MB. Once that size is reached, the current logfile is renamed and compressed to `application-1.log.gz` and a new `application.log` file is created to start appending new logging there.

This is my unified CloudWatch agent configuration:

```
{
  "agent": {
    "run_as_user": "ec2-user",
    "region": "${AWS::Region}",
    "debug": true
  },
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/var/log/my-application/application*",
            "log_group_name": "my-application-log-group",
            "log_stream_name": "my-application-log-{instance_id}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This setup works, but once my application generates a lot of logging (10,000,000 logging statements in 5 minutes), only ~6,000,000 of these end up in CloudWatch. The size of each logging line is estimated to be 228 bytes.

Does anyone know how I can make sure that the CloudWatch agent is able to send all logging to CloudWatch?

Comment: Your single java application is logging 33k lines per *second*???

Comment: That is correct! We have noticed this behavior with less logging but created a stress test that generates this amount of logging to make this investigation easier.

Comment: You could be hitting one or more of these rate limits: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html